# Pretrained keras model is returing the same result in android

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have created an image classifier in Keras, later I saved the model in `pb` format to use it in android.

However, in the python code, it can classify the image properly. But in android whatever image I gave as input the output is always the same .

This is how I have trained my model

```
rom keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)
classifier.summary()
classifier.save('saved_model.h5')
```

Later I convert that keras model(`saved_model.h5`) to tensorflow model by using [this](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow)

This is how I have converted my bitmap float array

```
    public static float[] getPixels(Bitmap bitmap) {

        final int IMAGE_SIZE = 64;

        int[] intValues = new int[IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE];
        float[] floatValues = new float[IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * 3];

        if (bitmap.getWidth() != IMAGE_SIZE || bitmap.getHeight() != IMAGE_SIZE) {
            // rescale the bitmap if needed
            bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE);
        }

        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
            final int val = intValues[i];
        // bitwise shifting - without our image is shaped [1, 64, 64, 1] but we need [1, 168, 168, 3]
            floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = Color.red(val) / 255.0f;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = Color.green(val) / 255.0f;
            floatValues[i * 3] = Color.blue(val) / 255.0f;
        }
        return floatValues;
    }
```

Later, I tried to classify image using tensorflow in android , like following .

```
TensorFlowInferenceInterface tensorFlowInferenceInterface; 
tensorFlowInferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(getAssets(),"model.pb");
float[] output = new float[2];
tensorFlowInferenceInterface.feed("conv2d_11_input",
                getPixels(bitmap), 1,64,64,3);
tensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"dense_12/Sigmoid"});
tensorFlowInferenceInterface.fetch("dense_12/Sigmoid",output);
```

Whatever image I gave the value of the `output` is  [1,0]

Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: Are you performing the **same preprocessing steps** as you have done before training of the model?

Comment: Yes, I did so . Shall I share my code ?

Comment: Yeah, but try to limit that to only relevant parts so that it could be easy for anyone to inspect it.

Comment: @today I have edited my question . Could u kindly have a look ?

Comment: Initially when I was playing around with TensorFlowInferenceInterface , I encountered a similar problem. But after switching to TensorFlow Lite, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color components returned by `Color.red(int)`, `Color.blue(int)` and `Color.green(int)` are integers in the range [0, 255] (see [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#red(int))). The same thing holds when reading images using `ImageDataGenerator` of Keras. However, as I stated in comments section, in prediction phase you need to do the same preprocessing steps as done in training phase. You are scaling the image pixels by `1./255` in training (using `rescale = 1./255` in `ImageDataGenerator`) and therefore, according to the first point I mentioned, this must also be done in prediction:

```
floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = Color.red(val) / 255.0;
floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = Color.green(val) / 255.0;
floatValues[i * 3] = Color.blue(val) / 255.0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply . I have changed my code according to your suggestion , but the result is still the same . I have also edited my question based on ur suggestion .

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro Well, I am not sure what else might be wrong. I have not worked with TF in android, so it's strange to me that it's returning `[1,0]`, i.e. two values which probably corresponds to thresholded and transformed value of the output of sigmoid layer with **one** unit. It seems it does some kind of **post-processing** internally or maybe you have configured it that way.

Comment: Seems I have found something , I just used 255 for dividing rather 255.0 .  Now I got something different . for cat image I got value something [3.0000e,0] and for dog image I got [4.000e,0] .I gave something completely different , I got something like [1.0000e,0]

Is there any logic , so that I can say which should I classify as cat and which one dog . FYI , I've trained my model , only to determine cat and dog .

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro I don't know what these values correspond to. In normal case, e.g. using Keras in python, the sigmoid returns float values in range (0,1). So I can't find out how to interpret `[3,0]` or `[4,0]` or even `[1,0]` as the output of a model which has a sigmoid layer with one unit as its last layer.